# C++ wrong function called?

Tags: c++, debugging, polymorphism

I have a C++ project in which I need to add functionality from a third party library.

I added the library to compile along with the my project however, without using it anywhere in my code. The problem is that just by adding the library to my codebase, my code breaks even though I am not using the new code I added.

I was wondering what could cause this behavior. Is it possible that instead of using some function of my codebase the linker imports functions with the same name from the library?

Note that although I mention that the added code is a library, I actually use the source code files directly in my Makefile, without compiling them into a shared library.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I think your question will be much easier to answer and much more valuable to others if we deal with specifics instead of speculation.  Please reproduce details from the problem here.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, there is not much more detail I can add since there is no apparent error (like segfaults) except that the program prints wrong results. The common third party libraries between my project and the library I added is libssl and libcrypto. Just wondering probable causes that could break my program when I am not actually using the new code added.

Comment: @user4242 The reason is that your code has a bug which causes undefined behaviour, most bugs do this. When you have undefined behaviour strange things happen, things which would make no difference to a bug free program (like adding unused code) do make a difference to a bugged program. All this is just a long way of telling you that you have a bug in your code, but there is nothing in your question that can help us diagnose your bug.